# Can a denied motion to intervene be appealed in itself?

Tags: united-states, federal-courts, appeal

From Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervention_(law)#United_States) on intervention:

> Rule 24(b) provides for permissive intervention, which is subject to the discretion of the judge hearing the case.

If the judge hearing the case denies a motion to intervene, can this (denial) be appealed in itself (to a higher court)? If not, does a denied motion to intervene still grant the would-be interventor the right to file an appeal on the substance of the lawsuit matter later?

A quick search shows that "interventions of right" (under Rule 24(a)) [can and have been](https://www.justice.gov/crt/case-document/united-states-v-new-orleans-response-opposition-motion-summary-reversal-and-cross) appealed, so I'm guessing appeal is possible for 24(b)... (Both the original plaintiffs and defendants are "appellees" in this 24(a) case I found, and the movant is the appellant.)

Comment: The question is not really can it be appealed, it is when it can be appealed and how. A denial of a FRCP 24 motion is interlocutory, so the hard point is what discretionary or mandatory right to appeal exists to appeal it immediately, rather than at the time that a final order is entered in the case.

Comment: @ohwilleke: Thank you. I see there's a [whole doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlocutory_appeal#Federal_courts) when such interlocutory appeals are to be heard, although not specifically for this Rule 24.

Comment: @Fizz Yes. Exactly.